# Choosing a part of a string

Tags: bash, shell

Basically I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What shall we set into managed mode? (e.g. wlan0)"
read thisend
sudo ifconfig $thisend down
sudo iwconfig $thisend mode managed
sudo ifconfig $thisend up
var=$(iwconfig wlan0)
```

What the script does (as you see) is to set the wireless card into managed mode, but I would like it to double-check at the end of the script if it actually is set in managed mode, which I'll write some comparison system for, but for now I just want to know if it's possible to strip out everything else from the output of `iwconfig wlan0` except for `Mode: Managed`, and write the remaining output into a new variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var = $(iwconfig wlan0 | grep -v 'Mode: Managed')`

from `grep` man page

```
 -v, --invert-match
         Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.
```

Comment: Thank you. I just returned to working with Linux and I had completely forgot about grep. I was actually looking for how to select just the `Mode: Managed` part. Cheers for the quick answer!

Comment: oh I miss the `strip` word; glad if it helps anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` or `sed` to extract just the part you want.